# Angular2 and ExpressJS API - Logged In Sessions Not working

Tags: facebook, api, express, angular, passport.js

Basically I have written and Angular2 frontend client that consists of a button, when you click this button it makes a very simple request to the expressJS and passportJS api using the following function:

```
socialLogin(){
    window.location.href='http://api.example.io/auth/facebook'; 
    console.log('social');
   this.authenticationService.getProjectsMain();
}
```

Once that is finished everything is fine, I can visit the api url:

http://api.example.io/v1/api/me

in my browser and see my facebook data, my problem is that when I try to get this json data from the angular2 frontend service its as though the login has never happened even though I have it open in another tab and can see that there is data on the API subdomain. I am doing a get request to the api url and its getting nothing, because nothing is there. I am guessing that this is some kind of persistent cookie but I am unsure of how to put all this together.

My app.js server file

```
const express          = require('express');
const passport         = require('passport');
const Strategy         = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const path             = require('path');
const favicon          = require('serve-favicon');
const logger           = require('morgan');
const cookieParser     = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser       = require('body-parser');
const routes           = require('./routes/index');
const loginfacebook    = require('./routes/login-facebook');
const callbackfacebook = require('./routes/callback-facebook');
const standardLogin    = require('./routes/standardlogin');
const me               = require('./routes/me');
const app              = express();




app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    console.log('origin ' + req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin );
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-type");
    next();
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/*app.use(require('express-session')({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));*/

app.use(require('express-session')({ 
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: '.example.io',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
    },
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true  
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/auth/facebook', loginfacebook);

app.use('/callback/facebook', callbackfacebook);

app.use('/v1/api/login', standardLogin);

app.use('/v1/api/me', me);

app.listen(80);

module.exports = app;
```